# Me redondea los decimales en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema,hice una funcion en C para sacar la superficie de una circunferencia,pero al indicarle el numero 3 me devuelve 28, y el resultado seria 28,27.No se si me podrian decir en que me estoy equivocando.Desde ya muchas gracias! (dejo el fracmento de codigo)

```
#include <stdio.h>

short superficieCircunferencia(short radio);

int main (){

short radioM;

 printf("\n Indique el radio de la circunferencia: ");
  scanf("%hd",&radioM);
   printf("\n La superficie es de: %.2f cm2\n",(float)superficieCircunferencia(radioM));

return 0;}

short superficieCircunferencia(short radio){
 float superficie;

superficie = (radio * radio)*3.1416;
printf("\n La superficie es de: %.2f cm2\n",superficie);
 return superficie;

}
```

Comment: Hola, haz probado a poner el valor retornado de la función en tipo float en vez de short?

Comment: Si le agregas un tipo short como retorno a la función, habrá pérdida de información, necesita ser de tipo float para que no ocurra ningún error.

Comment: Si mario y no sirvio,que me recomendarias Dave?

Comment: No se si vierion,pero dentro de la funcion puse un printf para ver el valor que me daba y era el correcto,osea que dentro de la funcion da el bien el resultado,pero cuando lo retorna al main se pierden los decimales parece.

Answer (score 2):

```
short superficieCircunferencia(short radio)
```

El tipo `short` **no admite decimales**, solo números enteros.

```
short miFunc()
{
  return (short)25.56;
}

int main()
{
  float dato = miFunc();
  printf("%.2f", dato);
}
```

Este programa va a imprimir `25.00`. Como ves los decimales se han perdido ya que el tipo `short`, como te he comentado, **no admite decimales**.

El problema se reproduce incluso si intento trampear el `short`:

```
short miFunc()
{
  float numero = 25.56;
  return numero;
}

int main()
{
  float dato = miFunc();
  printf("%.2f", dato);
}
```

En este caso, `numero` se convierte de `float` a `short` ya que es este último tipo el que va a devolver al función.

Para que el programa funcione correctamente tengo que usar un tipo que admita decimales, como son `float` y `double`:

```
float miFunc()
{
  return 25.56;
}

int main()
{
  float dato = miFunc();
  printf("%.2f", dato);
}
```

Mágicamente ahora el programa imprime el número pedido.

Pues bien, tu problema se soluciona de la misma manera... usa `float` en vez de `short`:

```
float superficieCircunferencia(short radio); // Ahora al funcion devuelve un float

int main (){

short radioM;

 printf("\n Indique el radio de la circunferencia: ");
  scanf("%hd",&radioM);
   printf("\n La superficie es de: %.2f cm2\n",superficieCircunferencia(radioM));

return 0;}

float superficieCircunferencia(short radio){
 float superficie;

superficie = (radio * radio)*3.1416;
printf("\n La superficie es de: %.2f cm2\n",superficie);
 return superficie;
}
```

Comment: Eferion muchas gracias por la respuesta y quedo todo muy claro... A mi me parecia que podia llegar a ser eso,pero el profesor (es para la facu esto) puso el ejercicio y paso el prototipo de la funcion y era con Short,no se si lo hizo para que sea una trampa o busque la forma de resolverlo. Pero bueno le dire que de otra forma no me daba el resultado correcto.Muchas gracias por todo!